# How to rewrite htaccess RewriteCond http_cookie into web.config alternative?

Tags: azure

I'm having a hard time rewriting the following RewriteCond into web.config alternative and would appreciate any help.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module in IIS 7, rewrite rules with conditions would look something like this:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="something">
        <match ... />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$" />
        </conditions>
        <action ... />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

You can also use the URL Rewrite GUI interface in a local IIS 7 install to help build your rewrite rules, and then open the corresponding web.config to see how it should look.